# Easy way to create gene plot in gviz?

Tags: gene, visualization, gviz

I would like to create a simple plot of a given human gene containing the main features, e.g. exons, introns, ORFs, transcripts etc. I understand that `gviz`  is a popular choice for this kind of thing, but most tutorials are massive overkill for what I want to do (I don't need fancy features such as importing BAM files and plotting coverage).

I was wondering whether someone can point me towards some sample code for creating a basic gene plot. It probably would be good to start by creating a dataframe containing all the features of my gene - is there a handy package that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If Python is an option, you could check [BioPython and GenomDiagram](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec336). This should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to make something like a "gene arrow map" and `[gggenes][1]` can help you (with some little tweaks) in case you are familiar with `ggplot2`.